# Laravel Multi Tenancy: User information fetched from main user table for tenant user

Tags: laravel-10, tenancyforlaravel

I have configured multi tenancy concept in Laravel. I am able to setup the application. For super admin user, login is working fine and adding tenant and creating domain is working fine.

For tenant login, when I login as tenant user, it gets login successfully with tenant login details but fetch user detail from user table of main DB not from the user table from tenant DB.